# Psuedo Class Selectors Within ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would appreciate a little assistance working with Psuedo Selectors for an ID within CSS.  I cannot seem to display the first line of an ID in small caps.  A snippet of both my CSS and the corresponding HTML is included for reference.

```
#introtext {
     margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
     background: transparent;
     font-face: "arial black";
     font-size: 22px;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .1em;
     line-height: 1;
     text-align: center;
     }

#introtext:first-line {
     font-variant: small-caps;
     }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="introtext"><span id="introcap">H</span><span id="introtext.first">ere you will       
 find links to Scouting related websites and forms.</div>
```

Comment: it's correct and should work , unless you have another selector that overides it. Did you refreh your page and CSS ?

Comment: It's working quite fine, http://jsfiddle.net/KsbmX/

Comment: I find your very same code to be working fine in IE, Chrome and FF.

Comment: works for me too, FF22

Comment: Missing the closing tag for the introtext.first span in your html.

Comment: That's a pseudo-element selector and not a pseudo-class by the way. Two different things. You can't just call them "pseudo selectors".

Comment: Working fine on my end too. But just a quick note, your :first-line should actually be ::first-line according to MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Perhaps...

...your expectations are incorrect (and I know your code has an error). While I agree with the comments here that your code is working as expected, I am speculating you are attempting something different.

**Did you want the first *sentence* in small caps?**

I noticed in your code you have the "opening" tag of `<span id="introtext.first">` but you failed to put the closing tag for that `</span>`. This is an error. However, if your intent is to have the whole first sentence to become `small-caps`, your code will still not work because the **`:first-line` pseudo-element does not look at the first sentence, but the first-*line*** (which varies based off of the container width).

**Additionally**

It is best to not use a `.` in an id, since the `.` is used for designating classes. And perhaps a class is what you really want anyway.

**Finally, A Solution?**

If my speculations about your goals are correct, then I recommend doing the following (keeping your `#introtext` css the same, but changing the html and `:first-line` code), as [demonstrated in this **FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsbmX/5/).

*HTML*

```
 <div id="introtext">
   <span id="introcap">H</span><span class="first-sentence">ere you will find  
   links to Scouting related websites and forms.</span> More text to follow 
   in a second sentence. And a third. Blah. Blah.
 </div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.first-sentence {
     font-variant: small-caps;
     }
```

**Although**

It almost appears as though you intend this to be a header (since the text is centered), so maybe something like this is more semantic and also eliminates the need for your leading "H" to be separate (unless you want ***OLD*** browser support). [Here is its demo **FIDDLE**.](http://jsfiddle.net/KsbmX/6/)

*HTML*

```
<div>
  <h2 id="introtext">Here you will find links to Scouting related websites 
  and forms.</h2> More text to follow in a second sentence. And a third. 
  Blah. Blah.
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
#introtext {
     margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
     background: transparent;
     font-face: "arial black";
     font-size: 22px;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .1em;
     line-height: 1;
     text-align: center;
     font-variant: small-caps; /*<-- moved this to here*/
     }

#introtext::first-letter { 
     font-variant: none; /*<-- reset the pseudo-element to normal */
     }
```